# pg_get_serial_sequence returns ERROR: column "---" of relation "---" does not exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

Using Postgres 11.5, I'm trying to manually insert some data (with specific key values) into a table that has a SERIAL PRIMARY KEY field, and then adjust the sequence of the SERIAL primary key field to return a value higher than the current max value. But I'm getting an error. Here is a simple table

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  FOO_ID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  VAL     INTEGER
);

INSERT INTO FOO (VAL) VALUES (4);
SELECT * FROM FOO;
-- returns one record with a FOO_ID of 1, as expected

INSERT INTO FOO (FOO_ID, VAL) VALUES (5, 5);
SELECT * FROM FOO WHERE VAL=5;
-- returns one record with a FOO_ID of 5, as expected
```

Next, I want to update the sequence so my next few inserts without explicit FOO_IDs wont collide with the one with an ID of 5:

```
SELECT setval(pg_get_serial_sequence('FOO', 'FOO_ID'), (SELECT COALESCE(MAX(FOO_ID), 0) FROM FOO));
```

but this portion of the above SQL is failing:

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('FOO', 'FOO_ID');
```

with this error:
ERROR:  column "FOO_ID" of relation "foo" does not exist
SQL state: 42703

What am I doing wrong, or is there a better way to do this?
It may be worth noting that I do have some tables for which my setval statement is correcting the table's sequence, but it doesn't work on all tables, and not on this simplified case.

Answer (score 12):

In my case the problem was the same, but the solution was slightly different. I hope that my answer will help others. The lower case of the table name did not help, because the application uses table names where the first character is capitalized (`Foo` instead of `foo`). In an e-mail from 2004 ([link](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/28121.1098940366%40sss.pgh.pa.us)) I got the right hint:

```
SELECT PG_GET_SERIAL_SEQUENCE('"Foo"', 'Foo_id');
```

So the table name must be in double quotes, surrounded by single quotes.

Comment: I would never have guessed this in 100 years.

Comment: It doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out its a case sensitivity issue.

```
SELECT pg_get_serial_sequence('foo', 'foo_id');
```

works!